# Keycloak Spring Multitenant Null Pointer Exception

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, keycloak

Source Code from : https://github.com/ineat/spring-keycloak-multitenant

Started Keycloak and added realms as instructed in the readme file.

Updated the Keycloak Json codes at respective places.

Started Spring Project.

Got the Following Exceptions upon calling "http://localhost:8081/multitenant" :

> 2019-03-20 18:34:28.195 ERROR 25640 --- [nio-8081-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing
>   /multitenant
>
> 2019-03-20 18:34:28.248 ERROR 25640 --- [nio-8081-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception
>
> 2019-03-20 18:34:28.249 ERROR 25640 --- [nio-8081-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing
>   ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
>
> 2019-03-20 18:34:28.251 ERROR 25640 --- [nio-8081-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception
>
> 2019-03-20 18:34:28.252 ERROR 25640 --- [nio-8081-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing
>   ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
>
> 2019-03-20 18:34:28.506 ERROR 25640 --- [nio-8081-exec-2]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing
>   /favicon.ico
>
> 2019-03-20 18:34:28.511 ERROR 25640 --- [nio-8081-exec-2]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception
>
> 2019-03-20 18:34:28.512 ERROR 25640 --- [nio-8081-exec-2]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing
>   ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
>
> 2019-03-20 18:34:28.514 ERROR 25640 --- [nio-8081-exec-2]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception
>
> 2019-03-20 18:34:28.515 ERROR 25640 --- [nio-8081-exec-2]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing
>   ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_191]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:964)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_191]   at
>   com.ineat.spring.keycloak.multitenant.HeaderBasedConfigResolver.resolve(HeaderBasedConfigResolver.java:21)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterDeploymentContext.resolveDeployment(AdapterDeploymentContext.java:88)
>   ~[keycloak-adapter-core-4.4.0.Final.jar:4.4.0.Final]  at
>   org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler.preflightCors(PreAuthActionsHandler.java:107)
>   ~[keycloak-adapter-core-4.4.0.Final.jar:4.4.0.Final]  at
>   org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler.handleRequest(PreAuthActionsHandler.java:79)
>   ~[keycloak-adapter-core-4.4.0.Final.jar:4.4.0.Final]  at
>   org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:81)
>   ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-4.4.0.Final.jar:4.4.0.Final]   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:472)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:395)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:349)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [na:1.8.0_191]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_191]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]

Please advice if there's any more configurations to be made/any errors i should fix.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spring-boot application you mentioned resolves and loads keycloak configuration for multi tenant based on header field i.e "realm: ORGA1".

but not sure why you are calling `http://localhost:8081/multitenant`

You are supposed to get token for the required tenant and then called the API by passing the right tenant in header of the request